# Raw socket use epoll without receiving ack packet

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, epoll, syn

I need to use **tcp half-open** scan to check the port status of a large number of servers.

I `sendto()` a packet with `syn=1` to destip's destport,and should `recvfrom()` a packet ,if `syn=1` and `ack=1`, port is open, else if `rst=1`, port is close.

I use **epoll** , after socket send packet，socket's status doesn't become `EPOLLIN`.

**Is that ack packet is not a EPOLLIN?**

I set `socket IP_HDRINCL` ，so I can build a pseudo header with `syn=1`
and i tried nonblock socket and block socket ，both doesn't work.

this is part of my code:

```
int main()
{
    char localIp[20] = {0}; 
    GetSelfServerIP(localIp);//to get local IP
    int epollfd = epoll_create(1);
    if (epollfd  == -1)
    {
        error(1, errno, "Error epoll creating");
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKET sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(!IS_VALID_SOCK(sock))
        error(1, 0, "Error socket initialization");
    if(SetNonBlock(sock) < 0)
        error(1, errno, "Error switching socket to non-block mode.");
    if(SetReusable(sock) < 0)
        error(1, errno, "Error making socket reusable");
    if(SetHdrincl(sock) < 0)
        error(1, errno, "Error making socket Hdrincl");
    struct epoll_event ev; //only one ev for test
    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLPRI;
    ev.data.fd = sock;  
    if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, ev.data.fd, &ev) == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error adding event m to epoll");
    char * targetip = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";//test target ip
    struct epoll_event events[1];
    memset(events, 0, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
    while(1)
    {
        Sendpacket(ev.data.fd,localIp,get_random_sport(),targetIp);//to send syn=1 packet to targetIp port 1 to 1000;
        size_t nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, 2, 1000);
        size_t i = 0;
        if (nfds == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error calling epoll");
        for (i = 0; i < nfds; ++i)
        {
            if ((events[i].events & EPOLLIN) == EPOLLIN ||
                    (events[i].events & EPOLLPRI) == EPOLLPRI)
            {
                int sock_raw;
                int saddr_size, data_size;
                struct sockaddr saddr;
                unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(65536); //Its Big!
                saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
                data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, &saddr_size);
                if(data_size <0 )
                {
                    printf("Recvfrom error , failed to get packets\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    return 1;
                }
                //Now process the packet
            }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

1.`events[i].event` always == `EPOLLOUT`

2.`data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, buffer, 65536, 0, &saddr, &saddr_size)` data_size always < 0.

Comment: Why not just use NMap, which has a built-in, very easy to use, half open SYN scan capability.

Comment: Because my boss don‘t allow me to use any external plugin or program